# How to link external Spring Boot JAR in manifest (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, manifest, noclassdeffounderror

I'll try to boil my issue down into a basic external JAR linking question, which I have not been able to find an example/answer for. I have 2 JARs, a.jar and b.jar, in the same directory. The `MANIFEST.MF` of a.jar contains: `Class-Path: b.jar`.

Essentially, I want to run a.jar that contains minimal application-level classes, but links to a large external b.jar with all other necessary classes. But running the command `java -jar a.jar` results in: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/MainApp`.

Not sure if it's relevant, but b.jar is actually a Spring Boot JAR which contains the expected classes (e.g. `com/example/MainApp.class`) in `BOOT-INF/classes`. The `MANIFEST.MF` of b.jar contains: `Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/`.

I want to know if there's a simple way to achieve this? Let me know if any more details are needed to diagnose the issue.

**Update:**
I copied the `com/example/MainApp.class` file to the base directory in b.jar, and the class was found! But I want to keep the original files in place. So I suppose that rephrases the question: how do you specify where classes are located inside the JAR?

Comment: this link should be useful [ https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven ]

Comment: well I'm not trying to build a single fat JAR and I'm pretty sure the other steps just create the manifest file as I already have it, pointing to the external JARs in `libs/`. is Maven doing anything more than my basic Class-Path manifest entry?

Comment: I use the maven plugin for spring boot application.the plugin create the jar with currect configuration in the build directory and you can run this jar file without problem.

Comment: yes, but I think you're misunderstanding my problem. my b.jar runs as a Spring Boot app with no issues... but my a.jar cannot link to the classes in b.jar because they are in `BOOT-INF/classes/com/etc` instead of `com/etc`

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like that path like "classpath: path/to/jar/b.jar"

Comment: see my update in the question. the path to b.jar already works, since it is in the same directory as a.jar... it seems i need to specify the path inside the b.jar folder structure itself

Comment: did you try specify it through /target folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?